# Problem with Webform Mail Chimp on Drupal 8.7.8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-webform

Recently we updated a website made with Drupal 8. The update was from core 8.6 to 8.7.8, at the same time all the modules were updated as well. Among those modules were **Webform** and **Webform Mailchimp**.

After that, some of the forms started showing a warning after the form is submitted.
The e-mail is sent and the data of the form is saved.

```
strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array is given in Drupal\webform_mailchimp\Plugins\WebformHancler\WebformMailChimpHandler->postSave()
```

The full error details can be seen here: https://prnt.sc/pn76pv

I'm new to Drupal so I think I should not go in the source file and make changes myself. How can I fix this?

Comment: The latest version of the webform_mailchimp modules seems to have changed the particular [line that is giving you the error](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform_mailchimp/blob/8.x-5.8/src/Plugin/WebformHandler/WebformMailChimpHandler.php#L320). The best place to ask about this error would be the [issue queue for that particular module](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webform_mailchimp?categories=All).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, we can see that `strlen()` receives an array instead of a string :

> strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array is given in [...] WebformMailChimpHandler->postSave()
>   (**line 320** of [...])

At [Line 320](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform_mailchimp/blob/8.x-5.8/src/Plugin/WebformHandler/WebformMailChimpHandler.php#L320) of this module, we have a call to `mailchimp_subscribe()` :

```
mailchimp_subscribe($configuration['list'], $email, array_filter($mergevars, 'strlen'), $configuration['interest_groups'], $double_optin);
```

The error is caused by what is passed in as the third argument : `array_filter($mergevars, 'strlen')`, meaning `$mergevars` - that is expected to be an array of strings to be filtered by `strlen` - contains an array instead of a string at some point.

**How to fix `$mergevars` ?**

We can see it's loaded from a config, and then altered by modules that implement some alter hooks :

```
$mergevars = Yaml::decode($configuration['mergevars']);

// Allow other modules to alter the merge vars.
// @see hook_mailchimp_lists_mergevars_alter().
$entity_type = 'webform_submission';
\Drupal::moduleHandler()->alter('mailchimp_lists_mergevars', $mergevars, $webform_submission, $entity_type);
\Drupal::moduleHandler()->alter('webform_mailchimp_lists_mergevars', $mergevars, $webform_submission, $this);
```

First, you may want to check if `$configuration['mergevars']` is correctly set.

Then, you can see what is happening and eventually fix `$mergevars` in your own hook_alter :

```
function MODULE_mailchimp_lists_mergevars_alter(&$mergevars, &$webform_submission, &$entity_type) {
  # debug/fix $mergevars
}

function MODULE_webform_mailchimp_lists_mergevars_alter(&$mergevars, &$webform_submission, &$WebformMailChimpHandler) {
  # debug/fix $mergevars
}
```

The issue is likely caused by a wrong `mergevars` alteration in one of the alter hooks. Note variables are passed by reference.

If you find that `$mergevars` actually is an array of string (is it seems all good) inside your module alter hook, it means that another contrib module acting *after* yours (@see module priority) is causing the issue.

Comment: You are right. Some hours later I managed to fix the erro with the Help of a Drupal specialist. ANd it's in the exact line and change you mentioned